# How to pass View element from React Native to Native Adnroid?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have some Android library that needs to use the `onScrollChangeListener` for the `ScrollView` that is used in React Native code. And I can't send only the values of the `ScrollView` change listener, it needs the whole view. I managed to link React Native and Android Native via Modules (according to [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android)) and it is working fine. I can call for methods and pass string values from RN to Android Native.

The question is how to send the whole scroll view (or any other view) to Native Android, because when i send the whole React Native Scroll View object i'm getting an error `maximum call stack side exceeded` - with call stack `isValidArgument`? Tried with `ReactScrollView` as argument it the java code, but still no success.

RN Code:

```
<ScrollView ref={(viewRef) => useView(viewRef)}>
...
const useView= (view) => {       
    console.log("RN Code: useViewfun called! " + scrollViewRN);
    MyModule.setScrollView(scrollViewRN);
}
```

Android Java Code:

```java
@ReactMethod
public void setScrollView(Object view) {
    Log.i("MyModule", "Android Code: setScrollView()");
}
```